# Error Message says "Type or namespace definition, or end of file expected"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm not sure what's up with my code and please bare in mind I have just started coding. please help!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public RigidBody rb
{}
    public float forwardForce = 2000f;
    public float sidewaysForce = 2000f;


    void Update()
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey("w"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(500 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }    
    }    
}
```

Comment: You need a class. `public class Whatever : MonoBehaviour { fields, properties, functions, etc. }` Here's an example from the Unity documentation for reference: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html Programming isn't really something you can do by accident. You'll need to study a bit to understand the fundamentals.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For the error you mention to go away you need to remove the last `}` in your code. You will also need to declare a `namespace` and a `class` as you cannot declare fields and methods without those. You should also initialize your `RigidBody`. In the end your code should look something like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public RigidBody rb;

        public float forwardForce = 2000f;
        public float sidewaysForce = 2000f;

        void Start()
        {
            /// Initialize rb here
        }
        void Update()
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);

            if (Input.GetKey("w"))
            {
                rb.AddForce(500 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be something like ```rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();```

Comment: You've really saved my bacon man! Keep up the good work you do! :)

Comment: Can you mark my post as an answer if it really helped you?